# Wording for post-graduation plans

Tags: capitalization, parallelism, phrasing

I am sending announcements about my daughter’s graduation from college.  I want to include a sentence about her post-graduation plans.  Originally I wrote,

> Rose will pursue her master of accountancy at XYZ University, after which she has accepted a position with ABC in Atlanta.

Concerned that there should be parallel structure between the verbs, I changed the second part to

> ...after which she will work for ABC in Atlanta

but I am not happy with the words “work for.”  Does anyone have a suggestion for alternative phrasing?   Also, should “master of accountancy” be capitalized?

Comment: Rose will now pursue accountancy at XYZ University, and she has accepted a position to work with ABC in Atlanta subject to gaining her master's degree.

Comment: **Why** are you not happy with *work for*?

Comment: Do you know what work she will do, and can you use that verb? Intern in Atlanta with her Master of Accountancy?

Comment: Good idea.  She will be an auditor.